# how to delete a node in a linked list without accessing its parent node?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have create a linked list of 4 nodes t1 t2 t3 t4 (in order),
such that

head=t1
t1->next=t2
t2->next=t3
t3->next=t4

t1->data=1 
t2->data=2 
t3->data=3

I want to delete t3 so that the linked list will print only 1 2.
But instead it is printing 1 2 0 4.

Also, after examining I found out that t2->next is not NULL despite the fact that t3=t2->next and I have already deleted t3.

so, How do I delete t3 without accessing t2?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct linkedList
{
    int data;
    linkedList *next;
}node;

node* getNewNode()
{
    node* nw=new node;
    nw->next=NULL;
    return nw;
}

void display(node* &start)
{   
    if(!start) return ;
    node *temp=start;
    while(temp)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    //create a linked list    
    node *head;
    node*t1,*t2,*t3,*t4;
    t1=new node;
    t2=new node;
    t3=new node;
    t4=new node;

    t1->data=1;
    t2->data=2;
    t3->data=3;
    t4->data=4;

    head=t1;
    t1->next=t2;
    t2->next=t3;
    t3->next=t4;

    //the linked list is 1 2 3 4
    cout<<"the original linked list is ";
    display(head);

    //now, delete t3
    delete t3;
    t3=NULL;

    //here, it is desired that the linked list prints 1 2
    //but the linked list prints 1 2 0 4 
    cout<<"the linked list after deleting t3 is ";
    display(head);

    //I don't understand why t2->next is not null
    //despite the fact that t2->next=t3
    //and I have deleted t3
    if(t2->next) cout<<endl<<"t2->next is not null"<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t2->next` is not `null` bc you did not set it to `null`. Deleting `t3` or setting `t3` to `null` does not set the other pointer in `t2` to `null`

Comment: Pointers are not automatically set to `0` when the object they are pointing to is destroyed. The pointer just holds the memory address, whether there is an object he does not care, but you have to keep track of it.

Comment: Your code is full of C-isms. Use C++. And use `std::list` (or just `std::vector`, which is almost always better anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to delete `t3` without accessing `t2` since your list is **singly linked**.

If you want to delete `t3` and `t4` you should do something like this:

```
t2->next=NULL;
delete t3;
delete t4;
```

If you just want to delete a single node somewhere in the middle of your list (e.g. `t3`) you also have to **adjust** the `next` **link** from `t2`:

```
t2->next=t4;
delete t3;
```

Otherwise it points to the deleted node.

Comment: Your answer is not even what he wants. He wants to print `1 2` and not `1 2 4`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Unless you explicitly store a pointer to `t3` somewhere else (which kinda defeats the point of this list), the *only* existing pointer to `t3` is held by `t2`. So to do *anything* with `t3` you need access to `t2`.

EDIT: but other than this minor detail, here is perhaps what you want.

```
void deleteNth(node* start, int N)
{
  node* prev = NULL, curr = start;
  while (N-- > 0 && curr != NULL)
  {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  if (curr != NULL && N <= 0)
  {
    prev->next = curr->next;
    delete curr;
  }
}
```

N.B. start counting `N` from 1 not 0.

Comment: Yeah 'I built a singly-linked list and it behaves like a singly-linked list, please help'  :((

Comment: @MartinJames yep lol. I think he has misunderstood the concept of memory access - OR confused lists with vectors...